# Export only headlines of a certain level

Tags: org-mode

This one is pretty straightforward. I'm translating in emacs org-mode, and my workflow looks a bit like this:

```
* Source text sentence

** Translation of source text sentence

* Another source text sentence

** The translation of that other sentence
```

What I'd like to do is take all (and only) second level headlines (which are my translations) and copy them into a separate document. Is this possible, or am I thinking too outside the box?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to delete them from the original?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200312/refile-from-one-file-to-other might be helpful. Since there is a `maxlevel` option there should also be a `minlevel` option? Then all that is left is to generalise the org-refile to all headers

Comment: I'd follow another strategy less prone to pitfalls to separate original from translation; let's say two identically structured subtrees which you can edit in two windows in the same frame, then exporting based on something else more sensible than "second levels" (like `noexport`). Said that @gregoryg answer does what you've asked for.

Comment: Not an answer, just to give you an idea for future projects: Org provides you with other structures than just outlines. One or more of them may give you a better "semantic mapping" for text-to-translation pairs. Consider each of the following: tables `(info "(org) Tables")`, description lists `(info "(org) Plain lists")`, properties `(info "(org) Properties and Columns")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach is to delete all non-level-2 entries before
parsing the export buffer. This is different to what @gregoryg is
proposing in that it also skips the body/text directly following
non-level-2 headings. No need to use tags.

```lisp
(defun export-translation (backend)
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda ()
     (unless (= (org-current-level) 2)
       (let ((beg (line-beginning-position))
             (end (or (save-excursion
                        (outline-next-heading))
                      (point-max))))
         (delete-region beg end))))))
```

You can add this function to `org-export-before-parsing-hook` as a
file variable by adding the following line to the beginning of
the Org document.

```
# -*- org-export-before-parsing-hook: export-translation -*-
```

Now to also skip the contents of level-2 entries, use:

```lisp
(defun export-translation (backend)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (while (re-search-backward org-complex-heading-regexp nil t)
      (let ((beg (save-excursion
                   (when (= (org-current-level) 2)
                     (forward-line))
                   (point)))
            (end (or (save-excursion
                       (outline-next-heading))
                     (point-max))))
        (delete-region beg end)))))
```

Comment: Nice! Note to the OP: note that this is a filter, so it does *not* change the Org mode buffer (or the file), just what is exported. And it is nicely generizable (e.g. this keeps headlines at level 2 only, but you can easily change it to keep headlines at level 2 or higher, or headlines between level 2 and 7 - if that fancy strikes you).

Comment: That function is not meant to be called interactively. That's why you're not seeing it. You should export as usual with `C-c C-e ...` I added another function that also skips the contents of level-2 entries. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Nice! I got it working. It works great, stripping out just the headlines that I want (though when it exports it still makes one big contents page thing out of all the headers - but I think that's probably related to something else). I'd love to hear about the function that strips the body text out - thanks so much! I'm still learning so much about this software and I sometimes still don't know what to do with some code. Thanks for this though, you've made my work significantly easier!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ox-extra` functions from the `org-plus-contrib` package.

This would require you to tag all top-level headlines with the "ignore" tag.

```lisp
(require 'ox-org) ; if exporting to Org Mode
(require 'ox-extra)
(ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines))
```

After tagging your top-level headlines, export to a plain text or Org file, e.g. `C-c C-e O o`

You can cancel your filter with

```lisp
(ox-extras-deactivate '(ignore-headlines))
```

As @NickD points out, this method removes the headlines only - it will still export any text under that headline.

Comment: One problem here is that only the headline is ignored: any text under that headline is retained. That  may not be a problem for the OP, but it might be a problem for others who find this in the future. You might want to note it in your answer.